# capture a regex group in url with pagejs

Tags: javascript, page.js

I want more than one optinal parameters in pagejs so I cannot go like this

`/controller/action/:p1?/:p2?`

because If p1 is not provided, value will be set to p1 instead of p2. So I went for this url form:

`/controller/action/p1/:p1/p2/:p2`

but this obligates the url to receive both param, so optional is now allowed,
So I'd like to make both param prefix and param receiver optional within a regex group, going in this url way:

`/controller/action(/p1/:p1)?(/p2/:p2)?`

however it doesn't work, it sets a function to p1...

any help on achieve this on pagejs ?

https://github.com/visionmedia/page.js